# How to pause a animation in nativescript-vue

Tags: animation, nativescript, nativescript-vue, pause

I use `AnimationSet` with `AnimationDefinitions` in my project.

When I call `AnimationSet.cancel()`, the element reset to its initial state.

It seems like the `cancel()` method can be customized. So, is there a way to save the current element state by custom the `cancel()` method and making it looks like a pause action? Or, is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by:

```
start() {
  // "Create new Animation with AnimationDefinitions with initial state or existing recorded state"
  // "Play and record state in the background in millisecond level"
}

pause() {
  // "Clear old Animation"
  // "Create new one with recorded state with setting the duration to 1"
  // "Play"
}
```

Maybe it's not a proper solution. But for now, I can only find out this hack way. And it just works fine for me.